# How do we parse a complex JSON within a DF while streaming with spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, spark-streaming, transformation

I'm trying to **read a TCP stream using spark 2.1.x** that gives a *batch of images and labels* in the given format:

```
{
  "0": {
    "img": // 3d image array
    "label": // string
  },
  "1": {
    "img": // 3d image array
    "label": // string
  },
  "2": {
    "img": // 3d image array
    "label": // string
  }
  ....
}
```

Example:

```
{
  "0": {
    "img": [[[255, 255, 255]]]
    "label": "Class1"
  },
  "1": {
    "img": [[[255, 255, 255]]]
    "label": "Class1"
  },
  "2": {
    "img": [[[255, 255, 255]]]
    "label": "Class1"
  }
}
```

This is my code to read this data from the socket:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 6100

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Image Classifier") \
    .getOrCreate()

dfFromStream = spark.readStream \
      .format("socket") \
      .option("host", TCP_IP) \
      .option("port", TCP_PORT) \
      .load()
```

dfFromStream seems to be a spark dataframe in the form:

```
+------------------------- +
|          value           |
+--------------------------+
| {"0":{...},"1":{...},... |
+--------------------------+
```

The **json object** under the value column is **stored as a string** in a *single row*.

I want the final spark dataframe to look like this:

```
+------------------+-------+
|       img        | label |
+------------------+-------+
| //3D numpy array |       |
| //3D numpy array |       |
| //3D numpy array |       |
+------------------+-------+
```

How do I perform this transformation? None of the transformations I do seem to work. Could anyone help me with this issue?

**Note:**

```
Example 3D Image Array:
[
  [[255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255]
   ....],
  [[255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255]
   ....],
  [[255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255]
   ....],
  .....
]

Example Label:
"Class1", "Class2", etc.
```

Comment: Could you provide an actual sample of your data? 3d image array is not very informative.

Comment: I've edited the question. The sample data format is given at the end. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you provide a full row of dfFromStream?
I'm quite sure you can solve this with `from_json` or `schema_of_json`

You can share using something like https://pastebin.com/